# how to get all attributes in prestashop

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop

I need to get all attributes that exists in my Prestahop store not matter wich or what product is assigned I just want to generate a array of those attributes and then use them in ProductController.php class. I check the file classes/Product.php and a method called getDefaultAttribute($id_product, $minimumQuantity = 0) is present but I think this only works for attributes assigned to a specific product and not return all as I need. Any help? I'm newbie with Prestashop and need to learn a lot of things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine file `classes/Attribute.php`. Your may use static function `Attribute::getAttributes($id_lang, $not_null = false)`. It return all attributes for a given language.

Comment: Thanks @alexander-simonchik after see the code I use this one made by me `$query_attributes = "SELECT ps_al.name FROM " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "attribute_lang ps_al LEFT JOIN " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "attribute_group_lang ps_agl ON (ps_al.id_lang = ps_agl.id_lang) LEFT JOIN " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "attribute ps_a ON (ps_a.id_attribute_group = ps_agl.id_lang) WHERE ps_al.id_lang = " . (int) Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
  $attributes = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query_attributes);
  $existent_attributes = array();
  foreach($attributes as $attr) {
      $existent_attributes[] = $attr['name'];
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all attributes by using this SQL query:

```
$atbt = "SELECT a.id_attribute_group , a.name 
              FROM  " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "attribute_group_lang a                   
              where id_lang='".$id_lang."'";
    $res = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($atbt);
    $product_result = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($res as $key => $row) {
     $sql = 'SELECT pal.name AS label,pal.id_attribute AS value,0 AS status' 
                . ' FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attribute AS pa
        RIGHT  JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attribute_group_lang AS pagl ON (pagl.id_attribute_group =pa.id_attribute_group)
        LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attribute_lang AS pal ON (pal.id_attribute =pa.id_attribute)
        JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute_combination  AS pacl ON (pacl.id_attribute =pal.id_attribute)
        JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute  AS pat ON (pat.id_product_attribute =pacl.id_product_attribute)
        JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product  AS prot ON (prot.id_product =pat.id_product)
        WHERE pagl.id_lang="'.$id_lang.'" AND pal.id_lang="'.$id_lang.'" AND pagl.id_attribute_group=' . $row['id_attribute_group'].' AND prot.id_category_default = "'.$id_category.'" GROUP BY pacl.id_attribute';

        $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.